# Slick Carousel Autoplay left or right when hover

Tags: slick.js

hi everyone here is my test page so you can see what help that i need, 
http://jjvirgin.24techstuddev.com/testpage/

i want to continues slide left or right when hover, cause at the moment its only sliding left or right once. i want to make it continue sliding to left when you hover on the left button, or continue sliding to the right when you hover to the right button.

here is the code that i used to make it slide once.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.slick-prev').mouseover(function() {
        jQuery('.swiper-wrapper').slick('slickPrev')
    });
    jQuery('.slick-next').mouseover(function() {
        jQuery('.swiper-wrapper').slick('slickNext')
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead ou using `'slickPrev'` and `'slickNext'` methods use `slickPlay` on `mouseover()` and `slickPause` on `mouseout()`